# When to use Gmapping?

Tags: navigation, gmapping

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello

I have some question regarding Gmapping. I would like to know when to use it. I have a sensor package consist of Laser range finder, IMu  and Camera. I was using amcl for the robot pose estimation. I do not have encoders(odometry) so was using IMU for the ICP in the laser scan matcher node. So I had an option oof using Gmapping , but I actually used the amcl with the laser scans. Any explanation of Gmapping??

Thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/49450/when-to-use-gmapping??/) by [Astronaut](https://answers.ros.org/users/2221/astronaut/) on ROS Answers with karma: 330 on 2012-11-29

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

- AMCL is a localization method that
  localizes your robot in a previously
  known map.
- Gmapping is a SLAM (simultaneous
  localization and mapping) method that
  simultaneously generates a map and
  localizes your robot in it.

In a nutshell (for details on the difficulties of the SLAM problem see for example [this overview paper](http://www-personal.acfr.usyd.edu.au/tbailey/papers/slamtute1.pdf)), SLAM can be more brittle than pure localization as the map used for localization is not static.

---

Originally posted by [Stefan Kohlbrecher](https://answers.ros.org/users/57/stefan-kohlbrecher/) with karma: 24361 on 2012-11-29

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 6